# Windows GDI - FillRect vs MoveToEx & LineTo?

Tags: windows, gdi

When reading source code which draws lines in Windows using [GDI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_gdi/) it is relatively common to see [FillRect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-fillrect) being used despite the only purpose being to draw a line.  But the end product of drawing a line with a width value and a filled rectangle are quite similar aren't they?

FillRect() is 1 function call, Using MoveToEx & LineTo requires 2

Which is more efficient when needing to draw a line, using [FillRect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-fillrect) or [MoveToEx(](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-movetoex)) and [LineTo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-lineto)?

Comment: FillRect is no substitute for LineTo, it can only draw perfectly horizontal or vertical rectangles.  Which is easy and obvious to do, perf is not much of a concern.

Comment: It makes a difference for printing. I think lines with thickness 1 are too narrow when printed, lines with thickness 2 are too thick. `FillRect` can be a solution, but that depends on map mode etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the most common cases, FillRect will do the same thing as MoveToEx and LineTo for perfectly horizontal and vertical rectangles. Nowadays, there are so many layers of indirection between GDI and the screen that the performance difference is almost certainly not relevant.

Drawing operations in GDI typically depend on the current "state" of the device context (DC).  Lines are drawn with whichever pen is currently selected into the DC.  The pen determines the color, style (solid, dashed, etc.), thickness, end caps, etc.

FillRect, however, doesn't depend on much of the DC state.  All drawing primitives depend on the mapping mode and clipping region, but, unlike lines, FillRect doesn't even depend on the selected brush, since you get to provide one right in the call.

Changing state (which objects are selected into the DC) can be a lot of work.  If you know you want a horizontal line, 2 pixels thick, in blue, it's a tad easier to use FillRect than to first create a pen, select it into the DC, draw your line, select the pen back out, and then decide how to manage the lifetime of that pen (when do you delete it?).  If the rest of the drawing is a bunch of dashed yellow lines with round endcaps, not having to keep switching state can make the code simpler.

Comment: A bit easier to use is FillSolidRect(), where you can simply provide a color and don't need a brush. I don't know if it's also a little bit faster, but probably hardly measurable.

Comment: @Nick: Or use the DC brush.  Or an opaque TextOut using the background color, which was once the fastest way to draw an axis-aligned rectangle.  Or maybe it was DrawText.

Comment: Creating a brush is what can be avoided by FillSolidRect, but using DrawText is a new approach to me (which also requires an additional function call SetBackgroundColor).

Comment: @Nick:  Yes, I understand.  The DC brush, however, is pre-created.  The TextOut (or DrawText) trick was supposedly faster in the days where GDI was hardware accelerated by your graphics cards.  If your drawing only one rect, then the time differences are probably negligible.  If you're drawing _n_ rects, then the setup cost (creating a brush, selecting it, or setting the background color, etc.) are amortized over the draws.